# Switching UI:Binder Widgets at runtime

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'd like to have a UI:Binder generated page where I can switch part of the UI at runtime. Here's an example:

```
//...More UI Binder stuff
<g:Widget ui:field="generalWidget" />
//...More UI Binder stuff
```

Now in my view implementation, I want to change the exact widget type that generalWidget shows. For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
@UiBinder Widget generalWidget;
...
if (<condition>) 
   generalWidget = new TabLayoutPanel(...);
else
   generalWidget = new FlowPanel(...);
```

However this doesn't work for me. When I hit the page, I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: This UIObject's element is not set; you may be missing a call to either Composite.initWidget() or UIObject.setElement()
```

in the Dev log. As far as I can tell, this is due to me using g:widget, because if I use the panels directly it works.

What's the best way to resolve this issue and get the switching widget behaviour I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `provided = true` on the `@UiField`:

```
@UiField(provided = true) Widget generalWidget;
```

And of course make sure you assign that field before calling `createAndBindUi`!

Comment: Hm. I added `provided`, and call `generalWidget = new Widget();` right before `createAndBindUi`, however I still get the same error. Also, will I be able to change what's assigned to generalWidget _after_ `createAndBindUI` is called?

Comment: Nevermind. I resolved this by initializing the panels and assigning one of them to generalWidget.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't look like I can switch the widget with just assignment. Is there some sort of redraw/refresh method I need to call? I currently only do this to switch: `generalWidget = instanceOfOtherWidget;`

Comment: If you want to switch dynamically (i.e. *after* `createAndBindUi`), then put a container in the UiBinder (e.g. a `SimplePanel`) and add your widget to that panel. Alternatives involve `HTMLPanel` and a container element (rather than widget).

Comment: I see. I was only using Widget because it was the common parent between the two widgets I need to switch. I wasn't aware that I could do this with a Panel. I'll try that now. Thank you.